# Jasypt and javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, jasypt

Does anyone know how to encrypt in javascript (maybe with sjcl?), post to a webapp and decrypt with java?

I wish to intercept some of a form data, encrypt it and then post to my spring application. ? already use jasypt PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC algorithm for database encryption.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use SSL?

Comment: well the simple answer is yes; there'n no support by an old load balancer :-(
This is of course a light-security solution.

Answer (score 1):

Any client-based symmetric encryption algorithm is likely going to be hackable since the code and keys is all sitting right there in the web page.

Wouldn't it be better to just use https to deliver the data to your server (the transport will be encrypted by https) and then do whatever final encryption you want on the server before storing it or passing to your spring application?

Comment: Symmetric encryption (which he seems to be using) won't work, but public-key encryption can be secure (from eavesdroppers, at least, not man-in-the-middle attacks).

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested https which is built-in public-key encryption and it's for the whole transport so it's even harder to hack than just data encryption in a non-encrypted transport.

Comment: of course I'm aware of the _un-secureness_ of this approach, still I'm looking for an answer

Comment: @Irkwz - Why?  Why choose the unsecure way that requires coding vs. the secure way that doesn't require coding?

Comment: (one liner) 'cause of customer requirement :-(
Actually because of old networking equipment not supporting SSL in a balanced environment.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: I've  found the precious jCrypting javascript library (based on jquery) and developed a spring integration (https://gitorious.org/jcryptingspring)